# Fail to upload windows dll due to 'Forbidden' (using PublishBuildArtifacts to Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, upload, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure build pipeline which uses a private build machine in our corporate network. As part of the pipeline a windows dll file and an exe file is created. Both files should be uploaded using a PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task:

```
- task:  
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'batchfiles/SSMD'
    ArtifactName: 'ssmd-$(SSMD_VERSION).0.$(Build.BuildId)-$(GIT_VERSION)'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

When uploading the windows dll file the following error occurs:

```
Fail to upload 'C:\agent-azure-v2.174.1\_work\1\s\batchfiles\SSMD\SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll' due to 'Forbidden'.
```

The upload of the exe file works fine.

Thanks for your help!

---

Detailed log information:

```
Starting: PublishBuildArtifacts
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish build artifacts
Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
Version      : 1.158.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts
==============================================================================
Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
Uploading 1 files
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Total file: 1 ---- Processed file: 0 (0%)
Fail to upload 'C:\agent-azure-v2.174.1\_work\1\s\batchfiles\SSMD\SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll' due to 'Forbidden'.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.Client.FileContainerHttpClient.UploadFileAsync(Int64 containerId, String itemPath, Stream fileStream, Byte[] contentId, Int64 fileLength, Boolean isGzipped, Guid scopeIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 chunkSize, Int32 chunkRetryTimes, Boolean uploadFirstChunk, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.Client.FileContainerHttpClient.UploadFileAsync(Int64 containerId, String itemPath, Stream fileStream, Guid scopeIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 chunkSize, Boolean uploadFirstChunk, Object userState, Boolean compressStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.FileContainerServer.UploadAsync(IAsyncCommandContext context, Int32 uploaderId, CancellationToken token)

Detail upload trace for file that fail to upload: ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll
Begin chunking upload file 'ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll', chunk size '4194304 Bytes', total chunks '2'.
Attempt '1' for uploading chunk '1' of file 'ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll'.
Generate new HttpRequest for uploading file 'ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll', chunk '1' of '2'.
Start uploading file 'ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll' to server, chunk '1'.
Chunk '1' attempt '1' of file 'ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll' fail to send request to server. Error: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException: Forbidden
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.Client.FileContainerHttpClient.UploadFileAsync(Int64 containerId, String itemPath, Stream fileStream, Byte[] contentId, Int64 fileLength, Boolean isGzipped, Guid scopeIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 chunkSize, Int32 chunkRetryTimes, Boolean uploadFirstChunk, Object userState).
Backoff 8.74 seconds before attempt '2' chunk '1' of file 'ssmd-21.0.0.106-gae26b4b/SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll'.

[...]
```

Comment: According to the error message, it should be related to the local agent machine policy. Please change the target file and try it again, then kindly share the result here.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT: Thanks for your response. What do you mean exactly when saying "please change the target file" ? What should I do differently? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I have found a work-around which fits me well. Before the build artifacts get published by the task PublishBuildArtifacts@1 they will be archived as zip using a task ArchiveFiles@2.

Answer (score 0):

> Fail to upload windows dll due to 'Forbidden' (using PublishBuildArtifacts to Azure DevOps)

According to your description, uploading the exe file is successful but the dll file fails.

That means our task or pipeline is correct. Then combined with the error log:

```
Fail to upload 'C:\agent-azure-v2.174.1\_work\1\s\batchfiles\SSMD\SSMD-21.0.0.106.dll' due to 'Forbidden'.
```

So we can speculate there should be a proxy block `.dll` file of your private build machine or corporate network. You should check it.

To verify it, you could try to use hosted agent to verify this issue.